# Return from netrw (Vim file explorer) to edited buffer?

Tags: vim

According to "Practical Vim" and the Vim help the shortcut `<C-^>` is supposed to return me to the edited file. I enter netrw using `:E`.

As an experiment I tried remapping the default shortcut as follows:

```
:nnoremap <C-y> <C-^>
```

Once I use `<C-y>` I get feedback:

```
E23: No alternate file
```

... but I don't get back to the edited buffer.

How can I return to the edited buffer, or for that matter, how can I debug this issue to find out what prevents me from returning to it according to the documented procedure?

NB: I am setting the mapping on the command prompt, not in `.vimrc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The alternate file is, practically speaking, the buffer that was open previously in the same window:

```
:e file1
:e file2
<C-^> shows file1
<C-^> shows file2
<C-^> shows file1
…
```

`<C-^>` is used to toggle quickly between two buffers *in the same window*.

You may not have an "alternate file" to jump to (probably a netrw thing which doesn't really makes sense to me) and `<C-^>` is of no use here.

Instead, use `:bd` which deletes the current buffer (netrw) and puts you back in the previous buffer. Note that you can use `:Rex` to get back the latest netrw window at any time.

If you don't open files (you use netrw to look around for some kind of info), your workflow could be:

```
:Ex
(exploration)
:bd
if you want to start a new exploration,
    :Ex
    :bd
if you want to explore from where you were,
    :Rex
    :bd
```

However, you should read `:h netrw` because it has more commands that would probably help you a lot: `:Hex[plore]` (opens netrw in an horizontally split window), `:Vex[plore]` (opens netrw in a vertically split window), `:Tex[plore]` (opens netrw in a new tab)… These commands will let you go on your safari while keeping some "state".

As an alternative, `<C-o>` and `<C-i>` are two handy shortcuts that let you go up and down the jumplist. In your situation, `<C-o>` may be the quickest way to get back to the previous buffer.

Comment: excellent answer. `:bd` is exactly what I was looking for in this case. The other commands are nice in a big window. Since I use `tmux` to split my workspace, the screen estate Vim gets is actually rather small.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how the mapping has anything to do with the `E23`; you should get the same error with the original `<C-^>` command. Probably, no alternate file has been set yet; some plugins also explicitly use the `:keepalt` command to avoid recording the buffer change.

You can check the alternate file name via

```
:echo expand('#')
```

or, in the output of `:ls`, look for the line that has a `#` sigil.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer. Alas, it's not helpful. When I use `:ls` I see the edited file *while* in netrw listed with `#`. However, that doesn't allow me to jump back - which is the essence of my question. I tried the remapping mostly because `^` is "harder" to synthesize on an US-English keyboard that a plain letter.